# TypeError: argument should be a bytes-like object or ASCII string, not 'Binary'

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, amazon-kms

I'm trying to validate user with username and saved encrypted password, the first lambda function gives an error as the type should not be binary, however in the second lambda function, which I used to save the username and password details, if I try to decrypt the same is working. I'm passing the same arguments in both the functions, however one is working and other is not, both are accessing the same dynamoDB table.
I don't know how to check which data type 'secret' supports, as per the error it says, object-like bytes or ASCII string. The password after encryption it is saved as binary in the table which automatically created by the function and the type was not defined manually.

I tried to import binascii and to convert the "password_from_table = binascii.b2a_base64(password_from_table)" and I got the below error.

```
Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "a bytes-like object is required, not 'Binary'",
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 37, in lambda_handler\n    password_from_table = binascii.b2a_base64(password_from_table)\n"
  ]
}



import boto3
import base64
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr

def decrypt(session, secret):
    client = session.client('kms')
    plaintext = client.decrypt(
        CiphertextBlob=(base64.b64decode(secret))
    )
    return plaintext["Plaintext"]

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    session = boto3.session.Session()
    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
    authentication_table_name = 'Authorization'
    #authorization_table = dynamodb.Table('GE_redo_authorization')
    authentication_table = dynamodb.Table(authentication_table_name)


    password = event['password']
    username = event['username']
    # Authenticate user with encrypted DDB

    entry = authentication_table.get_item(TableName=authentication_table_name, Key={'username':username})

    if 'Item' in entry:
        password_from_table = entry['Item']['password']
        decrypted_password_from_table = decrypt(session,password_from_table)
        decrypted_password_from_table = decrypted_password_from_table.decode('utf-8')
        if password == decrypted_password_from_table:
            return 'Correct password'
        else:
            return 'Incorrect password'
    else:
        return 'Invalid User'



Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "argument should be a bytes-like object or ASCII string, not 'Binary'",
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 36, in lambda_handler\n    decrypted_password_from_table = decrypt(session,password_from_table)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 10, in decrypt\n    CiphertextBlob=(base64.b64decode(secret))\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/base64.py\", line 80, in b64decode\n    s = _bytes_from_decode_data(s)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/base64.py\", line 45, in _bytes_from_decode_data\n    raise TypeError(\"argument should be a bytes-like object or ASCII \"\n"
  ]
}



import boto3
import base64
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

def encrypt(session, secret, alias):
    client = session.client('kms')
    ciphertext = client.encrypt(
        KeyId=alias,
        Plaintext=(secret),
    )
    return base64.b64encode(ciphertext["CiphertextBlob"])

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    plain_text_password = event['password']
    username = event['username']
    key_alias = 'alias/ProjectKey'
    table_name = 'Authorization'

    session = boto3.session.Session()
    table = boto3.resource('dynamodb').Table(table_name)

    encrypted_password = encrypt(session, plain_text_password, key_alias)
    decrypted_password = decrypt(session, encrypted_password)

    item = {
        'username':username,
        'password':encrypted_password
    }

    #check if item with the username already exists; if so, update password; else create new item
    entry = table.get_item(TableName=table_name, Key={'username':username})

    # if an entry with that username already exists, then update its corresponding password
    if 'Item' in entry:
        print("entry['Item']" + str(entry['Item']))
        response = table.update_item(
            Key={
                'username': username
            },
            UpdateExpression="set password = :p",
            ExpressionAttributeValues={
                ':p': encrypted_password
            },
            ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
        )
    else:
        #if an entry with that username doesn't already exist, then create it
        table.put_item(Item=item)
        new_entry = table.get_item(TableName=table_name, Key={'username':username})

        decrypted_password = decrypt(session, encrypted_password)

    return decrypted_password


def decrypt(session, secret):
    client = session.client('kms')
    plaintext = client.decrypt(
        CiphertextBlob=(base64.b64decode(secret))
    )
    return plaintext["Plaintext"]



Response:
"password"
```

Comment: 2 years and 2 months later, I am having the same issue.  Any luck?